# Repeated measures anova p-value not improving with larger sample size

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, p-value, inference, sample-size

**CONTEXT**:
I have an experiment of 2 groups of 20 individuals each (40 people total). The test group received an intervention to aid them in converting leads and the control group did not.

**GOAL**:
I'm interested in knowing whether the test group improved in their ability to convert leads relative to the control.

**ANALYSIS DESIGN:**
The baseline performance of each was calculated by looking at the 10 weeks prior to the intervention; that's performance at time 1. Secondly, the final performance of each group was calculated by looking at the 10 weeks after the intervention; that's the performance at time 2.

I've used a 2 period repeated measures anova on the point estimator of each person's performance to test for significance. The results were significant however what I've noticed is that a higher sample size does not seem to increase the sensitivity of the test.

**Question**:
Running the repeated measures anova with 38 degrees of freedom seems to only detect differences in the point estimators if it's at least 20% as a combined difference between periods.

What I thought to do was to run the repeated measures anova on the primary data (i.e. the combined data set of 1s and 0s for conversions and failures) for each person. The test is able to detect much smaller differences and its sensitivity has improved with the sample sizes I have i.e. over 3000 interactions per group per period.

My concern about this is the fact that the primary data is obviously not 3000 independent interactions since each person is responsible for 150 of them.

**And so, I was wondering if there might be a way of improving the sensitivity of a repeated measures anova test(or other inferential tests) in a scenario where the sample size of the participants is smallish (20).**

Comment: "My concern about this is the fact that the primary data is obviously not 3000 independent interactions since each person is responsible for 150 of them."

Did you consider using a mixed model instead?

Comment: I have not. Will try and report back.